# if then else loop macro in sas

Tags: macros, sas-macro

i'm trying to create if else loop  macro in sas  to create dummies for variables in a large dataset. the code i used is:

```
enter code here



%macro dummy(x,y,z);
data handle;
set handle;
%if &x='&y' %then %do;
&z=1;
%end;
%else %do; 
&z=0;
%end;
run;
%mend dummy;
```

and then i evoked the macro

```
%dummy(age_restriction,02,age_res1)
```

it created the var age_res1 but the condition did not get implied

using % sign with if else do directly uses the condition and does not produce the exact code but the condition also didn't ran

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I dont get the question.
But I found one error in the following line:

```
%if &x='&y' %then %do;
```

You have to replace the single quotation marks with double quotation marks to allow resolution of macro variable y.

And you should get into the diffrences between compile and run time regarding macro code.
Information about this topic can be found here among others:
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p067-27.pdf